# Resize event on multiple select control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multiple select html element.
I want to catch the resize event, so I can store the latest value.

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="ra-multiselect-collection" style="resize: vertical; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px; height: 527px;"></select>
```

The following code doesnt work:

```
$('.ra-multiselect-collection').on( 'resize', function(){
    alert('resized');
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid `resize` its a `window` event.

Comment: Yes, I know. Any other ideas?

Comment: What kind of *resize* you mean ?

Comment: When I resize an html element that has resize css property enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used resizable function from jQuery UI

http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

This is my code:

```
  $('.ra-multiselect-collection').first().resizable({
    resize: function() {
      alert('resized');
    }
  });
```

Maybe that `.first()` isn't necessary

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think that you can bind a resize event to a DOM element, but check this out:

```
$("select").on("mouseup", function()
{
    var el = $(this);

    if (el.data("old-height") == null || el.data("old-height") != el.height())
    {
        alert("resized!");
    }

    el.data("old-height", el.height());
}).data("old-height", $("select").height());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0d326ra/1/)

I have used `mouseup` event checking the old height stored in a `data` property with the current height on the moment of the event. If they are different, you get a *resize* event. Not a pretty beautiful workaround, but it seems to work.

I could not test on [IE because it doesn't support that property](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize) and on Firefox, it works nice but it seems that you can double-click the resize corner and it returns to the initial size and this doesn't trigger the event actually.

In your case, as you're using a class to select those elements, you can do this:

```
$(".ra-multiselect-collection").each(function()
{
    $(this).on("mouseup", function()
    {
        var el = $(this);

        if (el.data("old-height") == null || el.data("old-height") != el.height())
        {
            alert("resized!");
        }

        el.data("old-height", el.height());
    }).data("old-height", $(this).height());
});
```

Didn't tested but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have resize event here, but u can store the size on mousedown event, and check if it changed on mouseup event

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Well, author requested an event that doesnt exist, to check for resizing. I explained about the event, and my solution does check for a change in size, in a short and correct way. Thanks for sharing your opinion though

Comment: Some relevant code and examples would definitely help to improve your answer.